# How can this implication be equal to the set of all possible evaluations?

Tags: logic

I am having a hard time with this (simple) excercise in logic:

First, let us define the set $M$ which contains all possible evaluations.

Then, for each proposition sentence $A$, we define a set $[A] = \{ v \in M | v(A) = 1 \}$

So, the task is to show that $[A\rightarrow B]=M$ if and only if $[A]\subseteq[B]$

The reason why I am having a hard time understanding this is that imho M should contain *every* evaluation, including the one where $v(A)=1$ and $v(B)=0$. But, already the definition of $[A\rightarrow B]$ means that it can contain only those evaluations for which $v(A\land B)=1$.

So, even without the condition of $[A]\subseteq[B]$, how could $[A\rightarrow B]$ *ever* be the same group as the entire of $M$ if it by definition can't contain those evaluations in which it is not true?

I do not need a solution but simply an explanation of what I am not getting in this excercise...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A valuation $v$ satisfies a conditional $\phi\to\psi$ when: *if* $v$ satisfies $\phi$, *then* $v$ satisfies $\psi$.  Equivalently, $v$ satisfies $\phi\to\psi$ if it satisfies $\lnot\phi$ *or* satisfies $\psi$.  (This is the equivalence between $\phi\to\psi$ and $\lnot\phi\lor\psi$.)

Suppose that the set of valuations that satisfy a sentence $\phi$, that is, $[\phi]$ *is* a subset of the set of valuations that satisfy a sentence $\psi$, that is, $[\psi]$.  Symbolically,

$$ [\phi] \subseteq [\psi] \tag{1}$$

Now pick an arbitrary valuation $v_0$.  If it satisfies $\phi$, then it is an element of $[\phi]$, and so, by (1), also of $[\psi]$.  Then since $v_0$ makes both $\phi$ and $\psi$ true, it makes $\phi\to\psi$ true as well.  On the hand, if $v_0$ does *not* satisfy $\phi$, then it also makes $\phi\to\psi$ true, because a conditional is true in the case that the antecedent is false.  Since $v_0$ is arbitrary, we conclude that every valuation satisfies $\phi\to\psi$.

We started with the assumption that $[\phi] \subseteq [\psi]$, so our final conclusion is a conditional:

> If the set of all valuations that make $\phi$ true is a subset of the set of all valuations that make $\psi$ true, that is, $[\phi] \subseteq [\psi]$, then every valuation in $M$ satisfies $\phi\to\psi$.

That's one direction of the final biconditional.  The other direction is proved by *supposing* that $[\phi\to\psi] = M$.  You are right in observing that for some $\phi$ and $\psi$, it is impossible that this is actually the case, but for others it is quite possible, even when $\phi$ and $\psi$ are propositional variables.  For instance, consider the case $P \to P$, where $\phi$ is $P$ and $\psi$ is $P$.  At any rate, the proof would proceed by asking what it means that every $[\phi\to\psi] = M$.  It means that for every $v \in M$, $v$ satisfies $\phi\to\psi$.  What does that mean? … And so on, until reaching the conclusion that *if* $v$ is in $[\phi]$, *then* $v$ is in $[\psi]$, which implies that $[\phi] \subseteq [\psi]$.  (You said you didn't need a whole proof, so you can fill in the “…”.)  This direction concludes that

> If every valuation in $M$ satisfies $\phi\to\psi$, then the set of all valuations that make $\phi$ true is a subset of the set of all valuations that make $\psi$ true, that is, $[\phi] \subseteq [\psi]$.

Then the two are combined, and the biconditional is proven.

Answer (score 3):

You are not getting the following: When $A$ and $B$ are non single propositional variables, but setences as it is written, it may be possible, that $A \to B$ is a tautology, for example $A = p\land q$ and $B = p$, to give a trivial one. This is - that is what you should prove - always the case if $[A]\subseteq [B]$, which means the following: Every valuation $v$, which makes $A$ true, i. e. is an element of $[A]$, is an element of $[B]$, i. e. makes $[B]$ true, so there cannot be a $v$ such that $v(A) = 1$ and $v(B) = 0$. This $v$ would be an element of $[A] - [B]$.

Answer (score 1):

The existence of a $v$ such that $v(A)=1$ and $v(B)=0$ also depends on $A$ and $B$. For example, if $A=p$ and $B=p\lor q$ for some propositional letters $p,q$, then $v(A)=1$ *implies* $v(B)=1$. And that is the situation the exercise is talking about.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure I understand. Am I right to assume that $M$ does contain also the $v$ in which $v(A)=1$ and $v(B)=0$? And if this isn't the case, why?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are *sentences*, and the evaluation can be freely given only on *propositional letters* such as $p$ and $q$ in my example. A sentence can also contain logical connectives such as $\lor$ or $\land$ and $\lnot$.
$\quad$ So, once $p$ is evaluated as '*true*' by $v$,  then the sentence $p\lor q$ must be also evaluated as '*true*' by $v$. We can say that $v$ is a kind of *homomorphism* of Boolean algebras.

Answer (score 1):

Propositional valuations can assign truth values completely arbitrarily to the propositional *variables*, but the resulting values for compound sentences are then determined via the truth tables of the connectives, so they are not at all arbitrary.  For example, if $p$ is a propositional variable, then some valuations $v$ will have $v(p)=0$ and others will have $v(p)=1$, but for the compound formula $p\lor\neg p$, *all* valuations will have $v(p\lor\neg p)=1$.